# nexrender-cli video rendering is getting failed due to file read issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, worker, after-effects

When I changed my nexrender project from one server to another server, it is giving an error while rendering the files. below mentioned is the code where the rendering is getting stuck.

OS : Windows

After Effect : 2023

```
const JobRenderer = async (RequestID, JobFile, WorkDir) => {
    try {
        const DebugValues = Debug ? `--debug --skip-cleanup` : '';
        const Command = `nexrender-cli --file "${JobFile}" --workpath "${WorkDir}" ${DebugValues} --max-memory-percent 100`;

        return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            exec(Command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                console.log("error", error)
                console.log("stdout", stdout)
                console.log("stderr", stderr)
                if (error) {
                    console.log("error", error)
                    logger.error(`[ RequestID: ${RequestID} ] ${error.message}`);
                    resolve(false);
                    return;
                }

                if (stderr) {
                    console.log("stderr", stderr)
                    logger.error(`[ RequestID: ${RequestID} ] ${stderr}`);
                    resolve(false);
                    return;
                }

                logger.debug(`[ RequestID: ${RequestID} ] ${stdout}`);

                resolve(true);
            });
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    return false;
};
```

Here's the error result the code gives me when I tried to render

```
error Error: Command failed: nexrender-cli --file "C:\rendering\Jobs\273bb72a.json" --workpath "C:\rendering\.renderJob"  --max-memory-percent 100
> job rendering failed
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -4068,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:422:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5) {
  code: 1,
  killed: false,
  signal: null
```

I also printed "stdout" and "stderr"

```
stdout > starting nexrender-cli
using automatically determined directory of After Effects installation:
 - C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects 2023\Support Files\aerender.exe
checking After Effects command line renderer patch...
command line patch already is in place
[BgB-LsAbeNqJnW1b3fnsW] setting up job...
[BgB-LsAbeNqJnW1b3fnsW] working directory is: C:\rendering\.renderJob\BgB-LsAbeNqJnW1b3fnsW
[BgB-LsAbeNqJnW1b3fnsW] applying predownload actions...
[BgB-LsAbeNqJnW1b3fnsW] downloading assets...
[BgB-LsAbeNqJnW1b3fnsW] cleaning up...

stderr > job rendering failed
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -4068,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```